# Transitive vs Intransitive verb usage be verb as auxiliary

Tags: lie-lay-lain-laid

I need to know which version is correct. "The scissors are lying on the desk". "The scissors are laying on the desk".

Comment: This title really doesn't make sense! Please proof read it again and [edit] it.

Answer (score 3):

The two verbs have more differences than just transitivity vs. intransitivity - they mean different (though related) things.

*Lay* is a transitive verb meaning "gently put down XXXX."  Since it is transitive, it needs an object: `Please lay the scissors on the desk.`

*Lie* is an intransitive verb indicating that the subject is at rest: `Please lie down and close your eyes.`

So are the scissors themselves resting on the desk?  If so, use the intransitive verb *lie.*  If they are putting down something else [huh?] then use the transitive verb *lay.*

Final consideration:  the present participle of *lie* is *lying*.  The present participle of *lay* is *laying.*

You most likely mean to say  `The scissors are lying on the desk.`

Answer (score 2):

**lie** is intranstive, while **lay** is transitive. Thus:

--- **The scissors are lying on the desk.**

---**Pete lay the scissors on the desk.**

What makes this confusing is that the past tense of **lie** is **lay**, as in:

---**The scissors lay on the desk for a week before anyone claimed them**.

The past participle of **lie** is **lain** (uncommonly heard, at least in NA):

---**The scissors have lain on that desk for over a week now.**

If that sounds odd or unusual, it's probably because the other meaning of **lie** runs grammatical interference. With the meaning "tell an untruth," **lie** takes **lied** as both the past and past participle.

The past and past participle of **lay** are both **laid**:

---**Joe laid his report on the water cooler.**

---**Have you ever laid your glasses somewhere and promptly forgotten where?**